# The add button doesn't "add" the quantity, it only reloads the page

Tags: php, html

[image]

I can't figure it out thank you for reading
 I edit the code for many times but always conclude in the same result

here is the code (html):

```
<input type="number" size="2" title="Input value" placeholder="0" id="doni" 
name="Value"  required maxlength="4"onKeyDown="limitText(this,4);" />

<input type="submit" value="+" name="button" title="Add" onclick =action 
="addQuan.php"/>

 <?php
 include('connect.php');
 $id = $_POST['memi'];
 $a = $_POST['code'];
 $b = $_POST['bname'];
 $c = $_POST['Value'];
 $d = $_POST['price'];
 $e = $_POST['supplier'];
 $f = $_POST['qty_left'];
 $i = $_POST['dname'];
 $t = $f + $c;
 $sql = "UPDATE products 
 SET qty_left=? 
 WHERE product_id=?";
 $q = $db->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array($t,$id));
 header("location: products.php");?>
```

Comment: You will need to add the code from addQuan.php to help.

Comment: <?php
// configuration
include('connect.php');

// new data
$id = $_POST['memi'];
$a = $_POST['code'];
$b = $_POST['bname'];
$c = $_POST['Value'];
$d = $_POST['price'];
$e = $_POST['supplier'];

$f = $_POST['qty_left'];
$i = $_POST['dname'];
$t = $f + $c;
// query
$sql = "UPDATE products 
SET qty_left=? 
WHERE product_id=?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($t,$id));
header("location: products.php");

?>

Comment: Pleas edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: add content of the `connect.php` file. I do believe you face with connection error - just look at your logs and figure out what happens with your request.

Comment: btw: your screenshot doesn't contain button with name `add`. So you included something strange.

Comment: the "+" =add button

Comment: Will work just change its `type` to button ie. `type="button"`

Comment: doesn't work either